# Use $object->get_variable() in SQL Query [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop

I'm using a webform to write some data to an MySQL DB, 
when I receive the input data from the form i store it in an object;

But when I try to use this data in my SQL-Query, I get an error.

Could anyone help me pls?

thank you

K

This the initialisation of the object:

```
$nieuweInschrijving = new InvoerGegevens($voornaam, $achternaam, $functie, $bedrijf, $sector, $email);

class InvoerGegevens {

public $voornaam;
public $achternaam;
public $functie;
public $bedrijf;
public $sector;
public $email;
public $datum;
public $uniekeCode;
```

this is my class : InvoerGegegevens

```
function __construct($paramVoornaam, $paramAchternaam, $paramFunctie, $paramBedrijf, $paramSector, $paramEmail)
{
        $this->voornaam = $paramVoornaam;
        $this->achternaam = $paramAchternaam;
        $this->functie = $paramFunctie;
        $this->bedrijf = $paramBedrijf;
        $this->sector = $paramSector;
        $this->email = $paramEmail;
        $this->uniekeCode = $this->createUniekeCode();
        $this->datum = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
}
function get_voornaam()
{
    return $this->voornaam;
}
...
function get_uniekeCode()
{
    if(isset($this->uniekeCode))
        return $this->uniekeCode;
    else
        return 0;               
}


function createUniekeCode()
{
    // range is numbers (48) through capital and lower case letters (122)
    $range_start = 48;
    $range_end   = 122;
    $random_string = "";
    $random_string_length = 12;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $random_string_length; $i++) {
      $ascii_no = round( mt_rand( $range_start , $range_end ) ); // generates a number within the range
      // finds the character represented by $ascii_no and adds it to the random string
      // study **chr** function for a better understanding
      $random_string .= chr( $ascii_no );
    }

return  $random_string;
}
```

And This is my statement:

```
$echo = "INSERT INTO `tbl_inschrijving` (Voornaam, Achternaam, Functie, Bedrijf, Sector, Email, UniekeCode, Datum) VALUES('$nieuweInschrijving->get_voornaam();'....
```

The error i get is :

```
Notice: Undefined property: InvoerGegevens::$get_voornaam
```

Thank you for your advice

Comment: On which line of code does the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like

```
'$nieuweInschrijving->get_voornaam();'`
```

is interpreted as

```
$nieuweInschrijving->get_voornaam . '();'
```

instead of the intented:

```
$nieuweInschrijving->get_voornaam() . ';'
```

Use string concatenation, don't rely on PHP's interpretation.

---

You also need to escape input that goes into your queries.